# Netbeans doesn't recognize org package from geotools

Tags: java, netbeans, geotools

I was trying to install geotools into my java project in netbeans but it can't recognize all this packages:

```
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer; 
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
```

Those packages are taken from geotools Quickstart code for netbeans. I downloaded all manually, not using  maven. As i show, i tried a lot of releases:
[image]

I'm importing libraries in the wrong way? The files from above are in Libraries section of the project.

Comment: You should use maven to make your life easy. If you use the zip file then you need to unpack it before adding the necessary jars to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a `new Maven project` where you tell your pom.xml file to import all those dependencies via the online repositories, and setting in the pom.xml especially with the 26-snapshot property:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<geotools.version>26-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.13.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
<version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
<version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>osgeo</id>
<name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
<url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</releases>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
<name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
<url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</releases>
</repository>
</repositories>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Then, in your new maven project, you can import those dependencies like that:

```
package org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart;
import java.io.File;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
```

you can get the complete tutorial on this [link](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html). I did it with eclipse, but it shouldn't be an issue with netbeans